# Swiftにおけるヘッダの依存関係を知る方法

Tags: swift

以下のようなコードから、ヘッダに参照関係があることが分かります。

**A**:import Foundation

```
import Foundation

let randValue = arc4random()    // OK!
autorelease {                   // OK!
    var today = NSDate()        // OK!
}
```

**B**:import ObjectiveC

```
import ObjectiveC

let randValue = arc4random()    // OK!
autorelease {                   // OK!
    var today = NSDate()        // NG!
}
```

**C**:import Darwin

```
import Darwin

let randValue = arc4random()    // OK!
autorelease {                   // NG!
    var today = NSDate()        // NG!
}
```

**D**:pure Swift

```
let randValue = arc4random()    // NG!
autorelease {                   // NG!
    var today = NSDate()        // NG!
}
```

つまり、`Foundation`をインポートすると暗黙のうちに依存関係にある`ObjectiveC`と`Darwin`もインポートされるのですが、この依存関係を知る方法は存在しますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xcode上で`import Foundation`を右クリックして`Jump to Definition`を実行すれば依存関係をたどることは可能ですが、階層が深いので一筋縄ではいきません。

あまり分かりやすい形ではありませんが、実行可能ファイルにリンクされているライブラリを調べれば、間接的に依存関係が分かります。

```
import Foundation

println("Hello, World!")
```

```
$ xcrun swiftc main.swift -F /System/Library/Frameworks/ -I /usr/include/
$ otool -L main
main:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftDarwin.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftDispatch.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

`libswiftCore.dylib`だけは`Foundation`をインポートしなくてもリンクされるようです。
つまり、`Foundation`をインポートすると以下のモジュールもインポートされていることになります。

- CoreGraphics
- Darwin
- Dispatch
- ObjectiveC
- Security